# Login with Facebook In rails App without gem in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wanna create a login with facebook without using the gem. By using facebook-sdk i am getting `autoResponse: accessToken and userID`. Now I need to sign_up in my rails app on after success event FB.Login.

Please suggest how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a table to store the details that you get from facebook. On sucessful facebook signin save them to that table and then create a user using those details keep an association like

```
facebook_details belongs to user
user has many facebook_details
```

Using those associations create a user

Comment: Do I need user autologin after successful facebook sign_in? . This will not going to help me.

Comment: Can you clearly explain the process you need after successful Facebook login

Comment: I want to log in my rails app at the same time I am clicking on facebook login button. Right now I am getting error 401 Unauthorized.  I receive in params  ({"users"=>{"first_name"=>"XXXXX", "last_name"=>"XXXX", "email"=>"XXXXXXX", "fb_user_id"=>"XXXXXXXXXX," "action"=>"create"})

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table called `social_logins`, and assuming you have `users` table, you can build a `has_many` association b/w them, like `user` *has_many* `social_logins`, and in the `social_logins` table you could have a `type` column, which would store `facebook`, in the near future, if you want to implement let's say login with `twitter` or `google`, you can make use of `type` column and every other information could be stored in `social_logins` table.

```
class User < Activerecord::Base
  has_many :social_logins
end

class SocialLogin < Activerecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Make sure `social_logins` table contains `type` column, and other columns such as `authToken`, `user_id` and any other additioanl information you want related to social_login. You can also make use of additional data, such as `first_name`, `last_name`, and so on, and create a `User`(Sign up).

Steps you will have to do.

1. Click `Login with Facebook`.
2. Enter FB `email` and `password`.
3. On successful check, in `rails` check if the user with that `email` exists, if he does not, `create` the `user` and use the additional information you got in the response to sign up the user and `log` him into the `application`.
4. Next time, existing user clicks `Login with Facebook`, enters his `email` and `password`, check if the user exists in DB, he does, so log him into the application directly.
5. The sign up happens only the very first time he tries to `Login` using `Facebook`.

Comment: I had doubt on Point 3 and point 5. After entering user details in facebook I called ajax request for create user. How can create user without password?.

Comment: facebook does not return `password`, if you're not going to be using a `gem`, there are 2 ways. First, before you create a `user`, take him to the sign up form with additional information and ask him to enter `password`. Another approach is, generate a random password and you'll have to share that with him via email or sms and log him in, and have a sign_in_count, when `sign_in_count == 1`, take him to profile page, where he can change his password. This redirection should happen only the very first time he logs in via Facebook.